# netbeans read from standard input

Tags: netbeans-7

In NetBeans IDE 7.2 in a programme in Java I want to read from standard input. In the past there was a text box at the bottom of the output

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
int i = scanner.nextInt();
```

thanks in advance
Yiannis P.

Comment: `String javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(String)` can be used too!

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stick with System.in

Answer (score 0):

Right Click any where in inside the editor and then select Run File and then paste input in output box

Comment: OK. it works. You can also just click in the output box then write your input then press Enter